# Date.to_formatted_s() doesn't seem to work as advertised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, date

I feel incredibly stupid about asking this, but I'm clearly doing something wrong, and I would like to avoid a huge time sink (or I guess, *more* of a time sink).

I have the following setup in `config/initializers/time_formats.rb` (I created this file, since it didn't exist by default):

```
Date::DATE_FORMATS[:year_month_day] = "%Y%m%d"
```

What I want is for the `date` field of a model, when saved to the backend database, to be in the form `YYYYMMDD`, with no time component.

Now, inside of one of my model classes, I have the following method:

```
  # I know this would probably be better as `def date=(somedate)`, but to eliminate
  # the possibility of some kind of conversion error due to the name, I renamed
  # it to be `set_date`.
  def set_date(date)
    self.date = date.to_formatted_s(:year_month_day)
    puts(self.date)
  end
```

In my test, I have the following:

```
      mm = MyModel.new
      mm.set_date(Date.today)
      puts(wcf.date)
```

Both of the `puts` statements output `2021-02-15 00:20:21 UTC`, as they do if I change the `.to_formatted_s()` call to be `.to_formatted_s(:short)` (or pretty much anything I've tried, really).

I feel like I'm missing something simple here, and will likely slam my palm against my face HARD when I'm told what it is, but if possible, I'd like some assistance here.

Your reward for assisting me will be a video of said facepalming, if so desired. :D

Comment: What column type is `date`, if it is indeed a date column you cannot change how the database saves it. You have to format it in the view or wherever you are showing it.

Comment: @Eyeslandic Ah... the column type is `datetime`. Let me change it to `string` and see if that helps the situation. One thing that's strange, though - I'm looking at the migration in the database... would that affect the data member of the model, as well? I haven't actually saved anything to the DB yet...

Comment: The db column type matters yes, Rails tries to coerce the value. Save it as a date and then format it after you have read it back from the db.